# Calculating Sigma Summation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

It doesn't appear that there's a straightforward sigma summation function.  How would one calculate the following?

```
Σ(n=1 to x) of 5+floor(x/10)
```

Comment: For loop or while loop

Comment: y=0    for(n in x downTo 1) y+=(5+floor(n))

Comment: Something that doesn't require macros?

Comment: SUMPRODUCT..... Google sheets or Excel?

Comment: My code is in Kotlin, where do you want to calcuate sigma?

Comment: @BigBen - Google Sheets specifically.

Comment: @player0 - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fkqiqPX-1H7JAPIGhSoWopcRZ1mIUnga2qanC_pLEUA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM((SEQUENCE(1, DAYS(E1+1, E4), E4)*IF(F2="", 1, F2))^IF(H2="", 1, H2)))
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Place the *x-value* in cell **A1** and in another cell:

```
=5*A1+SUMPRODUCT(FLOOR(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A, A1))/10,1))
```

This is for Excel. For Google sheets:

[image]

much the same.